# Scanner not waiting for NewLine to collect input with a loop

Tags: java, loops, input

I am very new to coding and was hoping you guys could help me.
I am having an issue with nextDouble not waiting for a print.ln to collect data. 
With my priming input I have to put in two numbers for it to move to the next line and ask for the second number that I already put in because it didn't wait.
By that point it also decides to ask for the third number and accept input for that one as well, but it is fine asking for third and the fourth numbers with no issues.
It also happens inside the loop when it repeats.

I understand that using nextDouble doesn't mean it will "wait" for the newline and I know nextNumbertype doesn't have a newline flag but the usual trick of 
adding in "input.nextLine" after getting a double does not seem to be working.

I know I could just take all input as strings and convert them later, but this is a homework assignment and my prof seems to want things a very specific way.

Any ideas for what is wrong or what I could try?

Here is what outputs:

```
Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
1
4
Please input the x2 number:
Please input the y1 number:
1
Please input the y2 number:
5
Distance is 5.000000 

Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
```

Here is the actual code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class distanceFinder {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x1 = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");
    x1 = input.nextDouble();


    while(input.hasNext())
    {

    System.out.println("Please input the x2 number:");
    double x2 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please input the y1 number:");
    double y1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please input the y2 number:");
    double y2 = input.nextDouble();

    double x3 = 0;
    double y3 = 0; 
    double xy1 = 0;

    x3 = Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2);
    y3 = Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2);

    xy1 = x3 + y3;

    double distance = Math.sqrt(xy1);

    System.out.printf("Distance is %.6f %n%n%n",  distance);

    System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");
    x1 = input.nextDouble();

    }
input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: The problem is with `hasNext` as per javadcos *This method may block while waiting for input to scan.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Scanner.hasNext()` blocks until there's input. Once you type something, it enters the loop, executes the first print statement, grabs the input, prints the second statement, and waits for the next input.

Another issue is that you're checking `hasNext()` before reading `x2` instead of before `x1`. Try this structure instead:

```
System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");
while (input.hasNext()) {
    double x1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please input the x2 number:");
    double x2 = input.nextDouble();

    //...

    System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding guys! It works now (aside from properly quitting but I'll work on that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            double x1 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please input the x2 number:");
            double x2 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please input the y1 number:");
            double y1 = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please input the y2 number:");
            double y2 = input.nextDouble();

            double x3 = 0;
            double y3 = 0;
            double xy1 = 0;

            x3 = Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2);
            y3 = Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2);

            xy1 = x3 + y3;

            double distance = Math.sqrt(xy1);

            System.out.printf("Distance is %.6f %n%n%n", distance);

            System.out.println("Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
1
Please input the x2 number:
2
Please input the y1 number:
1
Please input the y2 number:
3
Distance is 2.236068 


Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
1
Please input the x2 number:
2
Please input the y1 number:
1
Please input the y2 number:
3
Distance is 2.236068 


Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
```

Comment: so push ctrl-z `Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at Main.main(Main.java:22)
`

Comment: Second time round also does not work - basically as per my initial comment using `hasNext` has not benefit

Comment: see `Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
1
Please input the x2 number:
2
Please input the y1 number:
3
Please input the y2 number:
4
Distance is 1.414214 


Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit
2
2
Please input the x2 number:
2
Please input the y1 number:
2
Please input the y2 number:
2
Distance is 0.000000 


Enter x1 or <crtl + z> to quit`

Comment: second time takes five inputs, also if ctrl-z is pushed at end of loop you get horrible exception message

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Thanks for your attention! I have corrected that